# c# How do I solve error mysql the used command is not allowed 1148?

Tags: mysql

I am executing a SQL query from C# but get the error:
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'The used command is not allowed with this MariaDB version'
Any help / pointers would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    private bool SaveCsvLines(string strFileName)
    {
        bool bResult = false;
        if (ConnectToDatabase())
        {
            // Here we load the string variable with the SQL we want to run
            string strLineInsert = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE " +
            "'" + strFileName + "' " +
            "INTO TABLE pfetest1.maerskInvoiceLine " +
            "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' " +
            "LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' " +
            "IGNORE 1 LINES " +
            "(container, " +
            "size, " +
            "vessel, " +
            "portOfLoad, " +
            "porCityCode, " +
            "portOfDischarge, " +
            "podCityCode, " +
            "postCode, " +
            "invoiceNo, " +
            "SET createdTimestamp = NOW(), " +
            "createdUserId = 1, " +
            "updatedTimestamp = NOW(), " +
            "updatedUserId = 1, " +
            "headerId = " + m_iFileId + ", " +
            "eta = STR_TO_DATE(@eta, '%d/%m/%Y')";

            //Now we execute that statement
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(strLineInsert, con);
            bResult = (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1);
        }
        return bResult;
    }
```

Comment: The query runs successfully in Heidi

Comment: I've noticed that \r\n was not showing up in the query, so I have since made it \\r\\n and now they do show up. However, I'm still getting the same error so it wasnt that.

Answer (score 0):

Switched to using MySQLBulkloader. That way I can define the columns etc. first then pump the data in.